# List all public packages in the maven-central registry

Tags: maven, maven-central

I am unsure if this question is a valid stack overflow question as it is not about my code (and I'm unsure if this satisfies website rules).

For research purposes, I want to get the list of `all` packages (include their metadata, if any) that are available on maven central. How can I do this?

I found this api guide - https://search.maven.org/classic/#api.

But it talks about a particular package named `guice` (correct me if I'm wrong).

I also found this - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ link which seems to have a list of packages (or `.jar` files).

Before this I have done my analysis on `npm` repository and I found the list of `all` packages easily on [this](https://replicate.npmjs.com/_all_docs?include_docs=true) like. I want something like that for maven central.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Cloud Java client](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java) to harvest the infro from the [Google Cloud Storage hosted mirror of the Maven Central](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/11/faster-builds-for-Java-developers-with-Maven-Central-mirror.html).

Comment: Forgive me for taking a long time. Can u please elaborate?